# What's the recommended way to open a new form and close the current/first form?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm building an application that have a initial form for login and if the user is authorized this form (login) should close and the application main form should open.

I was checking the SO for questions that would help and I found a lot of related questions, but I could not figure out which technique should I use, so I'm here asking. What is the recommend way to open a new Form and close the current?

I saw that some people recommended the OP to create a new thread and others recommended the usage of a "wizard" (I don't know what it is, but if that the best way please give me some resources to study).

I've tried to do it by closing the first and opening the second, but the application closes.

`this` is referring to the first form.

```
this.Close();
FormSecond f = new FormSecond();
f.Show();
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> if the user is authorized this form (login) should close and the application main form should open.

Recommendations number 1, 2 and 3 strongly state to **not** do this.  Adding your own authentication layer to the one that Windows already provides is never not a mistake.  You will *never* get it as secure and well tested as the Windows login.  And there's a serious security risk, users will re-use their login password.  If you need any extra info for a login beyond Environment.UserName and the groups the user belongs to then you can get that from the domain controller with the System.DirectoryServices namespace.

But you'll throw that caution to the wind.  The boilerplate solution is to modify the Main() method in Program.cs and use ShowDialog() to display a login form.  Which should return DialogResult.OK when the login is good, DialogResult.Cancel if it is not.  You use it like this:

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main() {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        using (var login = new LoginForm()) {
            if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        }
        Application.Run(new Form1());
    }
```

Comment: I don't get this. After conforming the user I want to show Frommain. but I don't get this "using (var login = new LoginForm()) {
            if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        }" What does it do? 
I changed my form1 to my form main, but it doesn't work, What does the mentioned code do? How can I fix this?

Answer (score -1):

This is how you do it:

```
FormSecond f = new FormSecond();
f.Show();
this.Close();
```

Answer (score -2):

If you start with the login form and close it, you no longer have any thread to run on. So (one of) the solution would be to run a different initial form and make that form launch the login form. Once the login form is no longer useful, you can close that and return control to the initial form. You can then spawn any kind of form as needed from the initial form.

Comment: Each form does *not* have its own thread, there is one shared UI thread.

Comment: "Imagine" is the keyword here.