# Open MDIparent from Login

Tags: c#, winforms, mdiparent

I have this in my LOGIN Form button

```
this.Close();
MDIParent1 mdi = new MDIParent1();
mdi.Show();
```

But MDI parent don't open.

Comment: Code after `this.Close()` guess it never reaches there

Comment: possible duplicate of [What's the recommended way to open a new form and close the current/first form?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135138/whats-the-recommended-way-to-open-a-new-form-and-close-the-current-first-form)

Answer (score 3):

Use `hide` instead

```
    MDIParent1 mdi = new MDIParent1();
    mdi.Show();
    this.Hide();
```

**EDIT :**

Another solution, in your `Program.cs`, Don't use `Application.Run(new LoginForm());`

```
    [STAThread]
    static void Main()
    {
        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);

        LoginForm lf = new LoginForm();
        lf.Show();

        Application.Run();
    }
```

Then you can use

```
    Application.Run(new MDIParent1());
    this.Close();
```

Answer (score 0):

You are closing your login form, and it cant open the mdi form.

A trick we have used a couple of times, is to first open your main form, then let that pop the login form. If the login fails, don;t close the login form. IN the login form's closing argument, end the application.

Not sure if this will apply to an MDI form, as I am not sure if you can open a modal form ontop of the MDI parent.

Answer (score 0):

Open your MDIParent-window at startup and open your Login-window from there (in the `OnLoad` for example with `ShowDialog`).

When Login fails you can exit the application.
If login succeeded, you can go on working with your MDIParent.