# how to close current form and open new form properly?

Tags: c#, winforms

I'm trying to close current form and open main form in my login. I'm trying to do it as given in the accepted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16135138/whats-the-recommended-way-to-open-a-new-form-and-close-the-current-first-form#16135462). This is how I modified my Program.cs. Login form works ok. It opens login form. But when I logged in how to show main? How to use this dialog result in my login form to show main.

```
  static void Main()
    {

        Application.EnableVisualStyles();
        Application.SetCompatibleTextRenderingDefault(false);
        using (var login = new frmLogin())
        {
            if (login.ShowDialog() != DialogResult.OK) return;
        }

        Application.Run(new frmMainAdmin());  
   }
```

How can I achieve this Dialog result given in the above code in my login form? I really don't get it.

Here's how I perform login in my Login form. in a button click event.

```
        SqlDataReader reader = new loginUserOP().userLogin(txtUserID.Text, txtpwd.Text);
            if (reader.HasRows)
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    LoggedUserInfo.lguserfname = (String)reader[0];
                    LoggedUserInfo.lguserlname = (String)reader[1];
                    LoggedUserInfo.lgusercategory = (String)reader[2];
                    LoggedUserInfo.lguserloginid = (String)reader[3];
                    LoggedUserInfo.lguserid = (int)reader[4];
                }
                reader.Close();
                }
```

Comment: Does `frmMainAdmin` happen have `Visible` set to `false` in the designer? `Application.Run` should make the form visible, you shouldn't need to do anything.

Comment: frmLogin virtually contains sensitive informaion (and resources), using statement simply dispose it. Of course if you need anything form it you have to save it to a variable outside that scope...

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti that is outwith the scope of the question.

Comment: @James No it's not false. What I don't get is , what is there to set when I perform log in functionality in Login form? Do I have to set any values when I perform log in to show that dialog result?

Comment: @chathwind I presume you see `frmLogin`? Well, in a real application you would need to of course validate the login details *before* you start then start the application. However, in the example, clicking OK on the login form is enough to assume the login is successful and the main form show show.

Comment: @James added the code I perform login.

Comment: @James from his comment on Hans' question it seems he's simply trying to read in frmMainAdmin what user entered in frmLogin

Comment: @chathwind just so I am clear, is the problem here you can't get `frmLogin` to close? i.e. the login page never closes after you login? I think I know what your problem is but I need more information.

Comment: @AdrianoRepetti Now I have provided how I perform login. I store login details not in login form. So can you help me with this problem? Where I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @James yes login form does not close. What are the info that you need?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code you have is fine, and will work, the problem is you never give it a chance to work because you never close `frmLogin`.

When forms are shown via `ShowDialog` they rely on the [DialogResult](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.dialogresult%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) property being set in order for it to determine which action to take - a form will generally read this in from a [button control](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.button.dialogresult(v=vs.110).aspx) on the form. You can set this at design-time, however, you need to validate *before* you set the result therefore you need to do something like

```
private void btnLogin_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (var reader = new loginUserOP().userLogin(txtUserID.Text, txtpwd.Text))
    {
        if (reader.HasRows)
        {
            while (reader.Read())
            {
                LoggedUserInfo.lguserfname = (String)reader[0];
                LoggedUserInfo.lguserlname = (String)reader[1];
                LoggedUserInfo.lgusercategory = (String)reader[2];
                LoggedUserInfo.lguserloginid = (String)reader[3];
                LoggedUserInfo.lguserid = (int)reader[4];
            }
            // remove the modal dialog and let the application start
            this.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
        }
    }
}
```

You should also notice that clicking the red X at the top right hand side of `frmLogin` kills the application, that's because `DialogResult.Cancel` is set automatically for you.